# How can i move this function out from app.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state

I intend to move out logic from my app.js. Right now, in app.js, I have a function that changes state of some variables in App.js. I want to learn what is the correct way to change the state inside app.js by letting app.js call a function (for example on click) that is in another component.

my app.js looks like the following:

```
const App = () => {
    const [opacity, opacitySet] = React.useState(1);
    const [showStep, setDisplayStep] = React.useState(true);
    const [isQrActive, setQrState] = React.useState(false);
    
/** code **/

  <ButtonContinue
    onClick={() => {
       stateChanger();
    }}
    style={{ backgroundColor: "black" }}
  >
    <p>cancel</p>
  </ButtonContinue>

/** lots of code **/

 function stateChanger() {  

   opacitySet(0);
     setTimeout(() => {

       opacitySet(1);
       setDisplayStep(!showStep);
       setQrState(!isQrActive);
     }, 400);

 }

/** and more code **/

}
```

I want to move the stateChanger function out from app.js, but still keep the same functionality. This in turn would allow me to call stateChanger from other classes easily.

Comment: Is there code missing from stateChanger? Doesn't seem like a lot to worry about moving. You can move out code to a custom hook that returns what the outside world needs (state , callbacks, setters). Setting state in a setTimeout like that is a memory leak if the component is unmounted before the timeout finishes btw, normally you would do async code in a  `useEffect` so you can cleanup on unmount

Comment: You can use redux to meet your requirements. If you want to do it without using redux you have to pass the function as props to all the child components.

Comment: That's it. I have more functions like these and they do approximately the same thing.

Comment: I think redux  will help you in this very situation https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution (which is also the most difficult to scale) is to pass the function as a prop to its children. You could also create a custom hook. But by declaring the state on the root-level component App and asking about how you can generally modify it from another component, we can interpret that the question is essentially about how to handle global state. You may want to consider using the Context API or Redux, which are tools created specifically for that purpose.

The most important thing to remember here is that if we have the option of maintaining the state reasonably close to where it is being used and modified, we should do that instead of handling it as part of a global state.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).